# How to insert a link to some file in multilangual website

Tags: joomla-3.x, multilingual

I have multilangual website with two languages. When I open article editor I try to insert to an article a link to some file for example to **REC.zip** that is in the root folder of my website

At the front-end I see that the link has url like `mydomain.com/REC.zip` so that's ok. But when I click the link, Joomla redirects me to the `mydomain.com/en/REC.zip` url so I get the 404 error

If I add to the `.htaccess` file the line

```
Redirect 301 http://mydomain.com/en/REC.zip http://mydomain.com/REC.zip
```

I get the 404 error again or get the endless looping error

How to fix it?

Joomla 3.5.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have this error because the default language in your site is "**en**", the language 
is managed by joomla!, not by directories, we have some solutions:

First of all, maybe the best way is create a new folder for your files in the default 
multimedia folder, in **your_site.com/images**:

images
- files
-- en
-- de

Add the link in your content like:

```
<a href="http://your_site.com/images/files/en/file.zip" target="_blank">Download</a>
```

or

```
<a href="images/files/en/file.zip" target="_blank">Download</a>
```

In modern browser you have this option:

```
<a href="images/files/en/file.zip" download="File Name">Download</a>
```

But, we have a problem with the above solution, if you want to restrict the access
 to the download file, other users can download the file withouth restriction if they 
have the full url.

Maybe the best solution is use some extension that makes use of MVC and allow
 restrictions, you can try with [OSDownloads](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension/directory-a-documentation/downloads/osdownloads) or [JDownloads](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension/directory-a-documentation/downloads/jdownloads).

Regards.

Comment: Thanks! I see that I can create any folder in the root directory of my website, not only inside of the `images` folder. And it still works